# Existe algum equivalente do RecyclerView em Swing?

Tags: java, swing

No Android Studio, utilizo uma classe chamada `RecyclerView`, que repete um layout enquanto houverem dados para isso, como se fosse uma lista. Existe alguma alternativa para isso em Java usando Swing?

Comment: Provavelmente não, tendo em vista que esse componente é relativamente novo no android, e o swing já está "nas ultimas", quase sendo depreciado no java.

Comment: O mais parecido que me lembro agora com esse componente é JList e JTable, com seus devidos abstractmodels.